# How to select specific value in foreach smarty?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, smarty

I am trying to get only 3 values from my array in foreach loop.I dont know how to do this.

In drop down, now i am getting all the five values from my array.But i need to have only starting 3 values from array not 4 and 5.

My code:-

```
    <select class="userCountryMapSelectMetrics" style="float:right;margin-right:0;margin-bottom:5px;max-width: 9em;font-size:10px">
            {foreach from=$metrics item=metric}
                <option value="{$metric[0]}" {if $metric[0] == $defaultMetric}selected="selected"{/if}>{$metric[1]}</option>
            {/foreach}
        </select>
```

Output:-

```
<option value="nb_visits" selected="selected">Visits</option>
<option value="nb_actions">Actions</option>
<option value="nb_actions_per_visit">Actions per Visit</option>
<option value="avg_time_on_site">Avg. Time on Website</option>
<option value="bounce_rate">Bounce Rate</option>
```

I need output to be:-

```
<option value="nb_visits" selected="selected">Visits</option>
<option value="nb_actions">Actions</option>
<option value="nb_actions_per_visit">Actions per Visit</option>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
 <select class="userCountryMapSelectMetrics" style="float:right;margin-right:0;margin-bottom:5px;max-width: 9em;font-size:10px">
        {foreach from=$metrics item=metric name=myMetric}
           {if $smarty.foreach.myMetric.iteration <= 3}
            <option value="{$metric[0]}" {if $metric[0] == $defaultMetric}selected="selected"{/if}>{$metric[1]}</option>
           {/if}
        {/foreach}
 </select>
```

See Smarty documentation page for [foreach](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach.tpl)

Answer (score 0):

Add condition to exit the loop when condition met like this

```
i = 0;

{foreach from=$metrics item=metric}
                <option value="{$metric[0]}" {if $metric[0] == $defaultMetric}selected="selected"{/if}>{$metric[1]}</option>
 if (++i == 3) {break;}
            {/foreach}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
{if $smarty.foreach.metric.index==3}{break}{/if}
```

Code:

```
  <select class="userCountryMapSelectMetrics" style="float:right;margin-right:0;margin-bottom:5px;max-width: 9em;font-size:10px">
      {foreach from=$metrics item=metric}
       {if $smarty.foreach.metric.index==3}{break}{/if}
       <option value="{$metric[0]}" {if $metric[0] == $defaultMetric}selected="selected"{/if}>{$metric[1]}</option>
      {/foreach}
  </select>
```